# When can I safely caulk a toilet after install?

Tags: toilet, caulk

Is there a timeframe after a toilet install where I can confidently caulk a toilet to the floor? I would assume after a day, if no leaks that the wax ring/seal is secure and can be safely caulked?
Also, is it recommended not to caulk all the way around the base of the bowl in case the seal should break and water seepage would indicate the seal has failed?

Comment: https://www.bobvila.com/articles/caulk-around-toilet/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to detect the leak, determine the floor level first to find out which way will it leak.

Main reason for Wax seal leaking is when toilet rocks.

Caulking will help preventing that.

If you want to way a day to check for leaks then do that.